# Undefined reference to clearly defined object

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I've got a very strange behaviour of the following definition

```
const TestListNew<ServerTestParams> test_list =
{
    "SERVER",
    {
        {func,  VALUE, "some string",  ENUM1_VAL, ENUM2_VAL}
    }
};
```

Where `TestListNew` is

```
template <class TestParamType>
struct TestListNew
{
    std::string module_name;
    std::vector<TestInfo<TestParamType> > tests;
};
```

And TestInfo is

```
template <class TestParamType>
struct TestInfo
{
    TestResult  (*function)(TestParamType * params);
    unsigned int code;
    const char * name;
    Enum1 enum1;
    Enum2 enum2;
};
```

I've got

```
In function `main':
/path/file.cpp:192: undefined reference to `test_list'
```

With nm returning

```
00000000 b _ZL9test_list
```

And what is the stangest thing is that when I move this definition to another source file all is OK, and nm says

```
0000000c B test_list
```

As I understand test_list is local symbol in the first case, but completly don't why it is so.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably related: `const` objects declared at namespace scope have static linkage (i.e. they are "private to" the translation unit that declares them).

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you. One file does not include header with extern declaration of test_list.